# Parse Javascript SDK in a node js environment and serverUrl

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, sdk, client

I am trying to use the Parse Javascript SDK in a node.js environment and I am completely baffled as to why I can't get this to work. I use Parse in a Swift iOS application, so I am familiar with Parse client code.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');

function ParseModule() {
  var self = this;

  self.initialize = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Parse.initialize("myAppID", "myJavascriptKey", "myMasterKey");
        Parse.serverUrl = "https://myserver.com/parse";
        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

        var query = new Parse.Query("MyClassName");
        query.find()
            .then(
                function(results) {
                    console.log("yay! it worked");
                    resolve();
                }
            ).catch(
                function(err) {
                    output.log("parse error: " + err);
                    reject(err);
                }
            );
      });
  }

  return self;
}

module.exports = new ParseModule();
```

When my module's initialize function is called, after making the 'find' call, in node-debug it just hangs node. In node it just exits the application, so I get no error. This is probably because the wrong (hardcoded) URL to the server is being used.

By the way, I really do want to use the master key not the Javascript key but the initialize method requires the Javascript key.

Also, when I step through the Parse SDK code, I get to this statement:

```
    var url = _CoreManager2['default'].get('SERVER_URL');
```

in RESTController.js. The server url that it's finding if from the 'config' object which seems to me to be the one used by parse-server. Thus, setting the serverUrl as instructed by the docs has no effect.

Am I not using the correct Parse NPM module? I'm new to node.js.

I'm wasting my entire personal project development day on this!!

Thanks,
Peter...

**UPDATE:** I've added the following line of code after the (almost definitely useless) set of the Parse.serverUrl=... . This seems to fix the issue.

```
Parse.CoreManager.set('SERVER_URL', "https://myserver.com/parse");
```

However, this seems like a hack to me. I would appreciate it if someone who is doing something similar to what I'm doing would tell me what I'm doing wrong (i.e. the right way to do this).

Comment: Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); is not work. You should query.find({useMasterKey:true} ) instead.

Answer (score 1):

***after making the 'find' call, in node-debug it just hangs node. In node it just exits the application, so I get no error.***

There are 2 points. First, Parse.Promise is not es6-like promise, and it do not have catch function.
https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Promise.html

Second, I have encounter lots of problems due to js sdk catch the exception. And I can't find it out. In your code, output is not defined, so there is a missing ReferenceError from output.log.

Try below code.

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');

function ParseModule() {
  var self = this;
  self.initialize = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        Parse.initialize("myAppID", null, "myMasterKey");
        Parse.serverUrl = "http://localhost:1337/parse";
        //Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        console.log(1);
        var query = new Parse.Query("MyClassName");
        query.find({useMasterKey:true}).then(
            function(results) {
                console.log(2);
                console.log("yay! it worked");
                resolve();
            },function(err) {
                try{
                    console.log(3);
                    output.log("parse error: " + err);
                    reject(err);
                } catch(error){
                    console.log(4);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        );

    });
  }

  return self;
}

module.exports = new ParseModule();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ChunTingLin. Yes, after posting this, I realized that catch was not going to work with Parse Promises and corrected that. A true Javascript/Node newbie error.

Comment: There is a short-coming of parse javascript sdk. It will catch some error, so that you cannot find where the problem is. I'm suffer this for many times XD.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem, and it was driving me batshit crazy.

From the Parse source code, I found the following:

```
  set serverURL(value) {
    _CoreManager.default.set('SERVER_URL', value);
  },
```

It looks like a member, but if you look closely it is not setServerURL, but set<space>serverURL.  It looks like a typo, but it seems to mean something.  I can find no reference to tell me what.